# Android Kotlin - Dialog Fragment Error (None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this Error on this line of my code it says:

```
 quantityFragment.show(fragManager, "Quantity")
```

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
>   show(FragmentManager!, String!) defined in com.company.kotlinecommerce.QuantityFragment
>   show(FragmentTransaction!, String!) defined in com.company.kotlinecommerce.QuantityFragment

ProductAdapter.kt

```
        itemView.bAddToCart.setOnClickListener {
            UserInfo.tempProdId = tempProdId

            // Show the fragment

            var quantityFragment = QuantityFragment()
            var fragManager = (itemView.context as Activity).fragmentManager

            quantityFragment.show(fragManager, "Quantity")

        }
```

QuantityFragment.kt

```
class QuantityFragment : DialogFragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
  inflater: LayoutInflater, 
  container: ViewGroup?,
  savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quantity, container, false)
  }
}
```

Please help me out ^_^

Answer (score 2):

You are using `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` so we need to pass `supportFragmentManager` instead of passing `fragmentManager` to the show method

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: @ItsLucid you can upvote and accept this answer.please.